# Animation with pure javascript, no jquery

Tags: javascript

I was using jquery/jquery-ui's `slideDown()` animation function for a particular task. It now transpires that I will not be able to use jQuery in this project. I also cant use YUI or any other libraries. So I wondering is there a way to perform a slideDown style animation using pure javascript?

**Edit:** I have to do it without jQuery because I am using selenium to control a webpage and on this particular site adding jQuery to the page breaks event handlers for some reason.

Comment: Why not just look at jQuery's implementation? It's just javascript in there.

Comment: If you don't want jQuery, why have you added the `[jQuery]` tag to your question? I've removed it.

Comment: @RobW The functionality in question comes from jQuery...

Comment: Agree with @antisanity. It's pure javascript in there so it IS possible. The thing is: such decision is cost effective? (to reinvent the wheel)

Comment: One thing I must point out: If you're being banned from using libraries then ask why and point out that you will end up re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: No jQuery, Yui, etc?  What a stupid requirement.  Anything written in JavaScript ultimately gravitates toward libraries.  Unless you are setting out with the purpose of writing a new library and have specific reasons for doing so, or just want to learn how other libraries work, why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is yes...quick question...couldn't you just do an ASYNC load of jQuery into the document and then use it after the fact, or can you not use it because of other limitations?

Worst case you could rip out the part you needed, but that doesn't make much sense. If you can edit any of the JS you could easily paste jQuery just above your code.

Comment: Adding jquery to the page breaks existing event handlers.

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery's `noConflict()` call? I'm not sure what other library you are using, but this is a pretty good way to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 5):

You can do slides and animations using CSS3, e.g.

```
.slidable {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: Slider 2s ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes Slider {
  from {
    top: 0px;
  }
  to {
    top: 100px;
  }
}
```

Use `-moz-` for Firefox. Javascript can do movements as well, just put them in timers, e.g.

```
var top = 0;
window.Timeout(MoveSomething, 10);
function MoveSomething {
  var el = document.getElementById('moveme');
  top += 2;      
  el.style.top = top + 'px';
  if (top < 100) window.Timeout(MoveSomething, 10);
}
```

Just takes coding!